My Desktop folder is suddenly missing from the Home folder
I use, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 64-bit: Gnome version 42.9: Wayland.
I have suddenly realised that my Desktop folder is missing. I noticed after a recent system  update, which I initially blamed for the problem. I wound my system back using Timeshift but my folder is still missing.
I have read several pieces of advice both from this sight and others on how to remedy the problem but nothing has worked.
Does anyone know how to fix this issue and why it might have occurred?
Thanks in advance.

I suggest checking what you're actually running, as a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system with all upgrades applied has reported itself as being 22.04.4 for some time now.  This link (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/) shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded to 22.04.4 before that date, so if you're still on 22.04.3 then you've not applied all security fixes or that is a clue of a significant issues you should explore (if the machine is used online!)

Was there anything of value in your ~/Desktop folder?   as why not just create a new one??  its only a folder (which has a purpose yes, but its commonly empty on most systems anyway)

@guiverc I rolled back my update and my system had not been updated for some time due to a lack of internet access. My current version is probably quite out of date. There was nothing on my desktop and thus, in the folder... however, there must be SOMETHING special about this folder because, if you just make one, it does not have a special icon or appear in the left panel of nautilus.

Files in your home directory are not part of the operating system and will not be affected by OS updates.   When accounts are created, initial contents of the account are copied from /etc/skel/ which might be updated by OS updates and package installations, but existing home directories are not updated.
The Desktop folder is not special, in the sense that is just a regular directory.  If it is missing, you can recreate it with mkdir ~/Desktop and you will have it back.  The only thing that makes it appear special is that a number of GUI components use it in a special way and may create it when they need it.
If you ran rmdir * in your home directory, all empty directories possibly including that one would be removed.   If this is something you do, you could prevent its removal with something like
 mkdir ~/Desktop ; touch ~/Desktop/.keep 

so that it isn't empty and removing it with rmdir will fail.
